# How to handle Error from users in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, security, error-handling

I am doing a security checklist for our database and there is one scenario its written

> Do not propagate errors back to the user. Log errors or transmit them
>   to the system administrator

How to view the proper error handling is enabled in database ?

Comment: This setting is for applications and websites; you don't have this kind of setting on SQL Server. If a user is using SSMS and runs the query `SELECT CONVERT(int,'a');` they're going to get the error `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'a' to data type int.`, and they should. SQL is a (query) language at the end of the day, and if the user is writing it and getting an error they need to know what that error is (otherwise how do they trouble shoot they're own SQL?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Error handling should be done in your application

Your database will not have any error handling mechanisms that are user-friendly. The closest you can get to this is performing checks on your data when returning it, such as using the `ISNULL()` function to check whether or not a column or value is null and then return an appropriate value in your query.

Aside from these, your error handling should be done in your application. Do extra checks to be sure that your queries are returning data, ensure it is in the right format, and check for nulls or empty values.

### How do I do that?

You could try simple checks when running a query, such as making sure an object is not null.

```
var user = _userManager.FindByEmail(email);

if (user != null)
{
    ....
}
```

### What should I do if it returns an error?

If your query returns an error for any reason, it should be handled within the code to throw a user-friendly page or error message such as

> Internal Server Error (500): Failed to load the users window

Provide the user the option to send the error report to you from their side.

**Also**

You should implement logging on server-side so that any time an error occurs, it is logged in a fair level of detail. You don't need to know *everything*, you just need to know what went wrong. Verbose logging should be an option though!

### To summarise

Your database will not handle errors - you need to do that yourself within your application. Make sure the user sees a generic and **friendly** message! Logging details server-side will be a life saver when it comes to fixing things!